# can't login when my password is up down left right

Tags: keyboard, login

I change my password by using passwd user <kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>←→</kbd> ，and I can login in at terminal, but after reboot I can't input <kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>←→</kbd> to enter gnome, as the EditText doesn't recognize them. Is there a way to login in without changing my password.Thanks.

Comment: Well the login-screen will use those key-signals no navigate the cursor and therefor not interpret them as part of a password. Therefor the best solution is most likely not to use such a password in the first place.

Comment: maybe it's the only way.

Answer (score 0):

If you hit Ctrl + Alt + F1 you should enter a terminal. See if you can change your password there.
If you hit Ctrl + Alt + F7, you should go back to the GUI.

Comment: yes, i see, i got it. but i still want to know if there is a way to login with this password.-_-||